# How to ignore non alphanumeric characters for SQL LIKE statement?

Tags: php, sql, ajax

I have an auto complete search box using ajax and its working as it should but its not efficient in finding things. I want to be able to search for something and not need to have commas or colons to actually return the correct result

e.g. if i want Terminator 2 : Judgement Day and i search terminator 2 judgement day it doesnt return anything because i left out the colon :. I dont want this to happen. Since its an ajax auto complete its easy enough to still find it but i want to be able to find things without needing to have non alpha numeric characters

Comment: You might want to look into full text search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For input `terminator 2 judgement day`, search on all words, not the string:

```
title LIKE '%terminator%' AND title LIKE '%2%' AND title LIKE '%judgement%' AND title LIKE '%day%'
```

Comment: is there a more efficient way to say break the string on a non alpha numeric character rather than white space? im aware i could use phps explode function to split the string on a specific character and make an array out of it but is there a way to identify if a string contains a character and split it on the character without knowing what it is other than not being 1-z or 0-9

Comment: `preg_split()` has this ability: preg_split('/[^[:alnum:]]+/', $str);

Answer (score 1):

If you are using string search using `like`, then you could do something like:

```
where replace(replace(replace(searchbox, ':', ''), ',', ''), '.') like
          replace(replace(replace(title, ':', ''), ',', ''), '.')
```

As you can see this is rather cumbersome.  You could simplify it by storing a "searchable" version of the title in the database with no punctuation and then removing any punctuation input by the user.

Or -- and this is probably the better solution -- use full text search, documented [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html).  For a search box, this is probably what you really want.  It handles punctuation and partial matches, for instance.